# Trying to make word search program in C

Tags: c, grid, binary-search, strcmp, wordsearch

Given an input dictionary read in from a file to use for all test cases, and several word search grids, i want to identify all words from the dictionary that appear in each word search grid.

I have read in the dictionary.txt file and I believe it can read in any grid of letters, I am having trouble trying to find the words in the grid that appear in the dictionary.txt file. I decided to use a recursive binary search on the string of characters going in all directions but it is a bit complicated for me.

My program runs until it gets to the word searching function where it tries to find the words in the grid and it'll crash but I dont know why and not sure if i am on the right track.

here is the piece i think is wrong,

```
int binsearch(char** dictionary, char** puzzle, int low, int high){

int mid;

if(low == 0 && high == 0){
    return 0;
}

mid = (low+high)/2 ;

if(strcmp(*puzzle,dictionary[mid]) == 0){
        //found a match
    return 1;
}

else if(strcmp(*puzzle,dictionary[mid]) > 0){
        //check upper half
    return binsearch(dictionary,puzzle,mid+1,high);
}

else if(strcmp(*puzzle,dictionary[mid]) < 0){
    //check lower half
    return binsearch(dictionary,puzzle,low,mid-1);
}
else return 0;

}

char wordSearch(char** dictionary, char** puzzle, int row, int col){

int i, X, Y, dir = 0;
char* wordsfound[20]= {'\0'};
for (X=0;X<row+1;X++){
    for(Y=0;Y<col;Y++){
        for(dir=0;dir<DX_SIZE;dir++) //check every direction
            for(i=0;i<19;i++){
                //will continue in direction DX,DY starting at x,y
                int nextX = X + DX[dir] * i;
                int nextY = Y + DY[dir] * i;
                if(nextX < 0 || nextX >= row) break; //keep in bounds
                if(nextY < 0 || nextY >= col) break;
                //store the string of letters
                *wordsfound[i] = (puzzle[nextX][nextY]);
                if(i>2){ //minimum word is 3
                //if the string of letters is actually a word, print
                    int bin = binsearch(dictionary,wordsfound,1,listlength);
                    if(bin){
                        printf("%s\n",wordsfound);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

}
```

but here is my entire code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define listlength 149256
#define maxWordLen 19


char** getWords(int rows, int cols);
void freeArray(char** array, int rows);
char** makeGridArray(int rows, int cols);
int binsearch(char** dictionary, char** puzzle, int low, int high);
char wordSearch(char** dictionary, char** puzzle, int row, int col);
const int DX_SIZE = 8;
const int DX[] = {-1,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,1};
const int DY[] = {-1,0,1,-1,1,-1,0,1};

int main(){

    //read in dictionary
    int i,j,x=0, numCases, gridRow, gridCol;
    char** words = getWords(listlength, maxWordLen);

    //Get number of cases.

    printf("enter number of cases:\n");
    scanf("%d", &numCases);

    //process each case.

    while(x < numCases){

        scanf("%d%d",&gridRow,&gridCol);

        //make word search grid
        char** grid = makeGridArray(gridRow+1, gridCol);

        /* for testing if grid is storing properly

        for(i=0; i<gridRow+1;i++){
            printf("%s\n",grid[i]);
        }

        */
        printf("Words Found Grid #%d:",x+1);
        wordSearch(words, grid, gridRow+1, gridCol);
        x++;
        freeArray(grid,gridRow+1);
    }
    freeArray(words, listlength);

}


char** getWords(int rows, int cols){

    int i;

    //allocate top level of pointers.
    char** words = malloc(sizeof(char*)*rows);

    //allocate each individual array
    for(i=0; i<rows; i++){
        words[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*cols+1);
    }

    //read dictionary.txt
    FILE *dictionary = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
    for(i=0; i<rows; i++){
        fgets(words[i], cols+1,dictionary);
    }

    fclose(dictionary);
    return words;
}

char** makeGridArray(int rows, int cols){

    //allocate top level of pointers.
    char** grid = malloc(sizeof(char*)*rows);
    int i,j;

    //allocate each individual array
    for(i=0; i<rows;i++){
        grid[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*cols+1);
    }
    //read in user input grid
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
        gets(grid[i]);
    }
    return grid;
}

int binsearch(char** dictionary, char** puzzle, int low, int high){

    int mid;

    if(low == 0 && high == 0){
        return 0;
    }

    mid = (low+high)/2 ;

    if(strcmp(*puzzle,dictionary[mid]) == 0){
            //found a match
        return 1;
    }

    else if(strcmp(*puzzle,dictionary[mid]) > 0){
            //check upper half
        return binsearch(dictionary,puzzle,mid+1,high);
    }

    else if(strcmp(*puzzle,dictionary[mid]) < 0){
        //check lower half
        return binsearch(dictionary,puzzle,low,mid-1);
    }
    else return 0;

}

char wordSearch(char** dictionary, char** puzzle, int row, int col){

    int i, X, Y, dir = 0;
    char* wordsfound[20]= {'\0'};
    for (X=0;X<row+1;X++){
        for(Y=0;Y<col;Y++){
            for(dir=0;dir<DX_SIZE;dir++) //check every direction
                for(i=0;i<19;i++){
                    //will continue in direction DX,DY starting at x,y
                    int nextX = X + DX[dir] * i;
                    int nextY = Y + DY[dir] * i;
                    if(nextX < 0 || nextX >= row) break; //keep in bounds
                    if(nextY < 0 || nextY >= col) break;
                    //store the string of letters
                    *wordsfound[i] = (puzzle[nextX][nextY]);
                    if(i>2){ //minimum word is 3
                    //if the string of letters is actually a word, print
                        int bin = binsearch(dictionary,wordsfound,1,listlength);
                        if(bin){
                            printf("%s\n",wordsfound);
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }

}


void freeArray(char** array, int rows){
    //free arrays
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<rows; i++){
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
}
```

Comment: `if(low == 0 && high == 0){
    return 0;
}` Termination condition is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
    char* wordsfound[20]= {'\0'};
    for (X=0;X<row+1;X++){
        for(Y=0;Y<col;Y++){
            for(dir=0;dir<DX_SIZE;dir++) //check every direction
                for(i=0;i<19;i++){
                    ...
                    *wordsfound[i] = (puzzle[nextX][nextY]);
```

Should be:

```
    char wordsfound[20]= {'\0'};                    /* not 20 pointers! */
    for (X=0;X<row+1;X++){
        for(Y=0;Y<col;Y++){
            for(dir=0;dir<DX_SIZE;dir++) //check every direction
                for(i=0;i<19;i++){
                    ...
                    wordsfound[i] = (puzzle[nextX][nextY]);   /* no '*' */
                    wordsfound[i+1] = '\0';           /* end the string */
```

Also, in your binsearch function when you go to check the upper half or the lower half, you need to make sure that `mid+1` and `mid-1` respectively are still valid indexes into the array.  If you access elements that are outside the array bounds, bad things are waiting to bite you.

For example, if `low = 0` and `high = 1`:

```
mid = (low+high)/2 ;       /* this is zero */
```

so you compare with the array element 0 and decide you need to look in the lower half, now you call with low as `mid-1` which is `-1`.  Oh noes!

Comment: it still crashes after trying that :/ maybe something else is crashing it?

Comment: Crashes on what line?

Comment: after i enter the grid array thru standard input. so i can enter number of test cases then enter row and col numbers and put in a char array of row by col then it will print "Words found Grid #1: and it crash

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
char* wordsfound[20]= {'\0'};
```

The above only makes all the 20 `char pointers` to point to NULL.

Then you are dereferencing

```
*wordsfound[i] = (puzzle[nextX][nextY]);
```

So, it crashes because `wordsfound[i]` is NULL.

**EDIT:**
So, you have to change the declaration of wordsfound.
If you change it to char wordsfound[20] as suggested by @John Hascall and @ J V A,
then you need to do this:

```
char wordSearch(char** dictionary, char** puzzle, int row, int col){

    int i, X, Y, dir = 0;
    char wordsfound[20]= {'\0'};
    for (X=0;X<row+1;X++){
        for(Y=0;Y<col;Y++){
            for(dir=0;dir<DX_SIZE;dir++) //check every direction
                for(i=0;i<19;i++){
                    //will continue in direction DX,DY starting at x,y
                    int nextX = X + DX[dir] * i;
                    int nextY = Y + DY[dir] * i;
                    if(nextX < 0 || nextX >= row) break; //keep in bounds
                    if(nextY < 0 || nextY >= col) break;
                    //store the string of letters
                    wordsfound[i] = (puzzle[nextX][nextY]);
                    if(i>2){ //minimum word is 3
                        wordsfound[i+1]= '\0'; // yes you need null char before passing to binsearch for strcmp to work.
                        //if the string of letters is actually a word, print
                        int bin = binsearch(dictionary, &wordsfound,1,listlength);
                        if(bin){
                           printf("%s\n",wordsfound);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

**i.e. you need to pass `&wordsfound` to `binsearch` because `binsearch` takes `char **` as second param.**

You can just pass `wordsfound`, but in that case, change the `binsearch` function's second argument to `char * puzzle` and use `puzzle` in `strcmp` instead of `*puzzle` inside `binsearch`.

But, If you are goal is not passing a single character to binsearch as Mr JVA as assumed, then you need to do differently. In that case you need to use 2-d char array or pointer to a char array. In that case, you need to change your current code in `wordsearch`. If you use `pointer to a char array`, then you need to allocate memory.

Comment: I think they don't want 20 character pointers.  I think they just want `char wordsfound[20]= {'\0'};`  and `wordsfound[i] = (puzzle[nextX][nextY]);` (and `wordsfound[i+1] = '\0';`)

Comment: Yes, you identified it.  But your proposed fixes (`You need to allocate memory Or just use a 2-d array.`) didn't include the correct one (`drop the *`).

Comment: so i changed it to just pass wordsfound by taking off the * the second argument puzzle and form the one in the strcmp, and took in your suggestions but it still crashes for some reason. also is the format of the wordsfound array not the way to approach it if my goal is to store just one string at a time. like once it stores 3 characters in it, i would it to check if that 3 char string exist in dictionary and it keep adding chars until 19 chars while checking after adding each char.

Comment: where does it crash now